# Deleting database row via PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I've looked through the "recommendations" based on the title I placed this as and the topics either weren't answered or didn't relate to my situation (from what I could see).

I've got a PHP HTML page that calls information from a database and inputs it into a table. I've got a a tag ready for a delete function but I just can't seem to get it right. I was hoping someone here would be able to help me out.

These are all the relevant pages.

connection.php

```
<?php
    try{
        $handler = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=data', 'root', 'root');
        $handler->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    }catch(PDOException $e){
        echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
?>
```

location1.php

```
<?php
include('connection.php');
$query = $handler->query('SELECT * FROM subsordered WHERE location ="location1"');
$delete = $handler->query('DELETE * FROM subsordered WHERE id = :id');

?>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 align="center">Location 1</h1>
    <table align="center" border="1" height="10%" width="80%">
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Desc</th>
            <th>Location</th>
            <th></th>
    </tr>
    <?php while($row = $query->fetch()){ '<tr>
        <td align="center">';echo $row[''],'</td>
        <td align="center">';echo $row['id'],'</td>
        <td align="center">';echo $row['name'],'</td>
        <td align="center">';echo $row['desc'],'</td>
        <td align="center">';echo $row['location'],'</td>
        <td align="center"><a href="connection.php?id='.$row['id'].'">Delete</a></td>
    </tr>';}  ?>
</table>
```

When I try to keep the mysql delete call in the first php section in location1 it breaks the page, I'm pretty sure it has something to do with the fact that I am assigning 2 calls to 1 function but I other than making a brand new page jsut for a single delete call I don't know what else to do

Comment: You should descide if you wish to query or delete someting, the way your code is, you always execure both SQL statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
<?php
include('connection.php');
$query = $handler->query('SELECT * FROM subsordered WHERE location ="location1"');
if (isset($_GET["id"])) {
  $delete = $handler->exec('DELETE FROM subsordered WHERE id = \'' . $_GET["id"] . '\'');
}

?>
```

This should work. Anyway, i would consider changing the code in order to prevent SQL injection (Check [this](http://php.net/manual/es/pdo.prepare.php))

Comment: That allows the page to still run. How do I run the delete call when I click on on the a tag? Also to do with the poor coding. I have used prepare in other sections of my program. This is just to get it running, from there I will make it more secure.

Comment: But, based in your code, you are doing a Server request each time you want to delete a record. WIth that code, you won't be able to delete a record without refreshing (if that is what you want). If you want to do it, you have to think about using ajax. Is that what you want? If not, i might have not understand your question correctly.

Comment: I was hoping to be able to delete the rows using just PHP and MySQL. Needing to refresh the page isn't a big deal because it can be done automatically. Ajax is brilliant I am using for a mobile aspect of this but I was hoping to avoid it for this section.

Comment: Well, in that case, isn't my first code working? Try by switching the order of the code, because it is getting the elements before deleting the record you want, so it will still show all the records despite one of them was deleted.

Comment: No, I checked the database just to make sure and it remained the same. I think the href may be the issue but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: I just edited my answer, removed the "*" from the delete query, i hadn't noticed that before. That may help. Your href looks good, i don't think that is the problem.

Comment: Still no change. I might start another version of this with Ajax and if I can't get this working I'll just use that. If you have any other ideas, let me know if not thanks for the help.

Comment: LOL! I just realized that "connection.php" is your database file, not your "list" file. You should use "location1.php?id=" in your href. Sorry about noticing it late :).

Comment: Brilliant, that worked. The reason I had it as connection was because I was basing it loosely off of another topic on this site and he has the delete query in the "connection" page. I suppose I should have noticed it as well. Thanks for the help mate.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not so familiar with PDO but from what I see this line has a problem:

```
$delete = $handler->query('DELETE * FROM subsordered WHERE id = :id');
```

It should be this I think:

```
$delete = $handler->query('DELETE FROM subsordered WHERE id = :id');
```

Have a look at the example here: http://www.mustbebuilt.co.uk/php/insert-update-and-delete-with-pdo/